# Saving integer input in a .txt file (Java)

Tags: java, file, input, output, file-handling

I'm trying to get the integers I enter to be written to a text file, yet however I edit the code my notepad spits out my integers as nonsense. Example:

Integer inputted: java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=1][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false]...

I believe my problem is in the line which I have marked with a "*". How would I go about fixing this? I believe it has something to do with the  "String.valueOf(input)" line. Full code linked below!

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
             System.out.printf("Please enter integer %d: ", i+1);
             numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

             {
                 try
                 {
                    *output.format("Integer inputted: %s%n", String.valueOf(input));
                 }
                 catch (FormatterClosedException formatterClosedexception)
                 {
                     System.err.println("Error writing to the file. Terminating.");
                     break;
                 }
                 catch (NoSuchElementException elementException)
                 {
                     System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                     input.nextLine();
                 }
```

http://pastebin.com/yV6dhSMt

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to write in to a file:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
writer.println("1");
writer.println("2");
writer.close();
```

And this to read from that file:

```
  String line, newLine;         // Variable to store a line and to check for a new line
  String[] splited;             // Variable to split text
  int lines = 0;                // Variable to check how many lines in a file

  Scanner myReader = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

  Numbers[] numbers = new numbers[2];

  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     lines++;
     for (int i = 1 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
           newLine = myReader.nextLine();
           splited = newLine.split(",");
           numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(splited[i]);
       }
     }
  }

  myReader.close();
```

I just wrote this here, but from what I remember this is how I did it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/MPrbLcO

Does this look about right? It's still giving me a blank document.

Comment: Alright, what a silly mistake by my part.

Now that's all good and well but I can't seem to print the integer to the file, but I can print anything else.

This is the line I'm working with:

"writer.printf("The inputted integer is %d\n", input);"

But I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.util.Scanner
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)

Comment: Instead of writing it like that, write it like this:
writer.printf( "Text: " + number[ i ] );

Comment: Alright, so far so good.

Now you don't think I should implement the entire second code you posted, right? Since I have the for loop already. Would I put it in a different method in that case?

Comment: Originally I had them separated in two different methods and then called them in the main, so yeah i recommend you put both of them in separate methods.

Comment: What's the purpose of this line?
"Numbers[] numbers = new numbers[2];" and it's giving me a type mismatch error. This line also gives me the same thing "numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(splited[i]);"

Comment: Yeah just use your regular int array

Comment: :( I still don't understand, it's so frustrating!

http://i.imgur.com/zf4yLFa.png

How would I implement the int array?

(thank you for your continued patience)

Comment: The same way you did when you stored them at the beginning.

Comment: Alright, all is well, except it wants me to add an opening bracket "{" and when I do, it gives me three "cannot handle exception" errors on the scanner, bufferreader and while loop lines. Here's what I'm seeing http://i.imgur.com/a8cJUe6.png

Comment: @Walby your safest bet would be to put the two in separate methods and call them in the main.

Comment: Alright totally rethought things, and came up with something else. Would you mind taking a look at what I put up above? : )

Comment: What am i looking at?

Comment: Well it's another way of opening/writing/closing/reading a file. Everything looks to be in working order until I have to read the file, then I'm stuck. http://pastebin.com/fxncB8VV  It's giving me an error on just one line, which is commented (the errors is written on the line).

Comment: @Walby believe it's not that hard. I gave you the concept and you can re arrange it to fit your program. That's the fun part of coding. Just make sure your code is clean so you can see where the error is coming from.